# How to draw a vertical line on the chart in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Im a beginer with Visual Basic. Im trying to draw a vertical line on X asix of the chart, but could not find a way to do so. Please advise.

```
Private Sub Chart()

'Display Chart
Chart1.Series("ScoreChart").Points.Clear()
For xx As Integer = 0 To DataGridView4.RowCount - 1
    Me.Chart1.Series("ScoreChart").Points.AddXY(DataGridView4.Rows(xx).Cells(0).Value, DataGridView4.Rows(xx).Cells(DataGridView4.ColumnCount - 1).Value)
Next
```

End Sub

[Like this in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XP9x.jpg)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.postpaint?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Can you please give me an example code

Comment: Use what you know to find some, google "chart postpaint draw line".  Lotsa hits.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code to add a vertical line.

```
    Dim verticalLine As VerticalLineAnnotation = New VerticalLineAnnotation()
    verticalLine.AxisX = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX
    verticalLine.IsInfinitive = True
    verticalLine.ClipToChartArea = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Name
    verticalLine.LineColor = Color.Red
    verticalLine.LineWidth = 2
    verticalLine.X = 2
    Chart1.Annotations.Add(verticalLine)
```

Result looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the Dim that the previous answer wrote and this worked much better

```
Dim verticalLine = New DataVisulization.Charting.VerticalLineAnnotation
verticalLine.AxisX = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX
verticalLine.IsInfinitive = True
verticalLine.ClipToChartArea = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Name
verticalLine.LineColor = Color.Red
verticalLine.LineWidth = 2
verticalLine.X = 2
Chart1.Annotations.Add(verticalLine)
```